# Fortran: output large array - exceeded length, split on two lines

Tags: fortran

In a Fortran program, I need to write an array into a file with a specific format.
I perfectly works for smaller array (e.g. alen=10 in the example below), but won't work for bigger arrays: it then splits each line into two, as if a maximum number of characters per line was exceeded.

Example (very similar to the structure in my program):

```
PROGRAM output_probl
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: alen=110          
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(alen)::a
INTEGER :: i,j

OPEN(20,file='output.dat')
30  format(I5,1x,110(e14.6e3,1x))

DO i=1,15
 DO j=1,alen
  a(j)=(i*j**2)*0.0123456789
 ENDDO
 write(20,30)i,(a(j),j=1,alen)
ENDDO

END PROGRAM output_probl
```

It compiles and runs properly (with Compaq Visual Fortran). Just the output file is wrong. If I for example change the field width per array item from 14 to 8, it'll work fine (this is of course not a satisfactory solution).
I thought about an unsuitable default maximum record length, but can't find how to change it (even with RECL which doesn't seem to work - if you think it should, a concrete example with RECL is welcome).

This might be basic, but I've been stuck with it for some time... Any help is welcome, thanks a lot!

Comment: this should work just fine. Are you sure whatever you are using the view the file isn't autowrapping?

Comment: Actually yes, you are right. I was post-processing the output file and it didn't work though it worked perfectly well in the past for a long time. Actually a change associated to the increase in array size (which I thought caused the output to be wrong) was also associated to a trouble in the output format (field filled with *) because of one single extreme value. I couldn't spot it until your remark made me use another viewing program where the output appears correctly, which made me look elsewhere. @Vladimir F, thank you too - your info also helped me resolve troubles with recl.

Answer (score 3):

Why not stream access? With sequential there is allways some processor dependent record length limit.

```
PROGRAM output_probl
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: alen=110          
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(alen)::a
INTEGER :: i,j

OPEN(20,file='output.dat',access='stream', form='formatted',status='replace')
30  format(I5,1x,110(e14.6e3,1x))

DO i=1,15
 DO j=1,alen
  a(j)=(i*j**2)*0.0123456789
 ENDDO
 write(20,30)i,(a(j),j=1,alen)
ENDDO

END PROGRAM output_probl
```

As a note, I would use a character variable for the format string, or place it directly in the write statement, instead of the `FORMAT` statement with a label.

Fortran 95 version:

```
PROGRAM output_probl
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: alen=110          
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(alen)::a
INTEGER :: i,j,rl
character(2000) :: ch

inquire(iolength=rl) ch

OPEN(20,file='output.dat',access='direct', form='unformatted',status='replace',recl=rl)
30  format(I5,1x,110(e14.6e3,1x))

DO i=1,15
 DO j=1,alen
  a(j)=(i*j**2)*0.0123456789
 ENDDO
 write(ch,30)i,(a(j),j=1,alen)
 ch(2000:2000) = achar(10)
 write(20,rec=i) ch
ENDDO

END PROGRAM output_probl
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir F, but unless I am wrong this is a Fortran 2003 only feature? I look for a more general solution (the program is old)...

Comment: And regarding your note, @Vladimir F, I agree - this would also typically allow the format to be updated if 'alen' must change (it must then be included in the character variable for the format string). The code above is sub-optimal (from an old program...)

Comment: See my edit for direct access version. Can be improved somewhat, adjust the buffer as you wish.

Comment: Stream access is great, but, AFAIK, pgi doesn't support it yet :-/.  Seriously Portland Group -- That standard is 10 years old now and we pay how much for your compilers???   ;-P

Comment: You must have an old release, PGI claims to support FULL Fortran 2003 already.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF, even though the problem was elsewhere (see comment in the original question above) your F95 solution with recl works and is of great help too.

Answer (score 0):

The program below should test. With Absoft compiler it works fine for n=10000, 10 character words, that is a line 100000 characters wide (plus a couple) in all. With G95 I get a message "Not enough storage is available to process this command" for n=5000 (n=4000 works).
      character*10,dimension(:),allocatable:: test
      integer,dimension(:),allocatable::itest

1     write(*,*)'Enter n > 0'
      read *, n
      if(n.le.0) then
         write(*,*)'requires value n > 0'
         go to 1
      endif
      write(*,*)'n=',n
      allocate(test(n),itest(n))

```
  write(test,'((i10))')(i,i=1,n)
  write(*,*)test

  open(10,file='test.txt')
  write(10,*)test
  write(*,*)'file test.txt written'
  close(10)

  open(11,file='test.txt')
  read(11,*)itest 
  write(*,*)itest
  end
```