# Unwanted newlines in large file output

Tags: fortran

I'm having troubles getting my code to write its results in the correct form.

The problem seems very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751073/fortran-output-large-array-exceeded-length-split-on-two-lines) but it did not help.

When I run the following code, the output file "results/traj.dat" should contain only one line but in fact all the data in spilt into to lines.
This issue only occurs from N_BOD=8, the file is correctly written if N_BOD=7 and IPOSITIONS is initalized with an according amount of numbers.

It's been suggested that there may exist some compiler option that I should use in order to allow large outputs without extra newlines but I did not find any (I'm using gfortran).

```
program ephemerids  
implicit none    
  integer,parameter :: N_BOD=8                                                                    
  character(len=30) :: OFMT2   

  real(8),parameter,dimension(3*N_BOD) :: IPOSITIONS=(/ &
    0.00450250878464055477,0.00076707642709100705,0.00026605791776697764,&
    0.36176271656028195477,-0.09078197215676599295,-0.08571497256275117236,&
    0.61275194083507215477,-0.34836536903362219295,-0.19527828667594382236,&
    0.12051741410138465477,-0.92583847476914859295,-0.40154022645315222236,&
    -0.11018607714879824523,-1.32759945030298299295,-0.60588914048429142236,&
    -5.37970676855393644523,-0.83048132656339789295,-0.22482887442656542236,&
    7.89439068290953155477,4.59647805517127300705,1.55869584283189997764,&
    -18.26540225387235944523,-1.16195541867586999295,-0.25010605772133802236/)

  OFMT2 = "(22E18.8E3)"
  open(20,file='results/traj.dat',status='replace')                
  write(20,OFMT2) IPOSITIONS  
end program ephemerids
```

Edit : as asked by francescalus, here's the output I get :

```
   0.45025088E-002   0.76707645E-003   0.26605790E-003   0.36176270E+000  -0.90781972E-001  -0.85714974E-001   0.61275196E+000  -0.34836537E+000  -0.19527829E+000   0.12051742E+000  -0.92583847E+000  -0.40154022E+000  -0.11018608E+000  -0.13275994E+001  -0.60588914E+000  -0.53797069E+001  -0.83048135E+000  -0.22482887E+000   0.78943906E+001   0.45964780E+001   0.15586958E+001  -0.18265402E+002
  -0.11619555E+001  -0.25010607E+000
```

Comment: 8*3 is 24, which is larger than the 22 repeat count in the format.  But you should post the output from your run so we can confirm this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you ! I feel a bit stupid now because I only took for granted that I had done the format right the first time but that was the problem, indeed.